# Array max function using Indirects (Excel)

Tags: excel

I am having trouble incorporating the Indirect function into an array function that returns the row number of the number closest to but less than/greater than the inputted number.

Traditionally, I use the functions below (both arrays) to get the location of a # closest to but less than and closest to but greater than, respectively, the given input:

```
{=MAX(IF(C21:C24<=C26,ROW(C21:C24),0))}
{MAX(IF(I1282:I1298>=M1294,ROW(I1282:I1298)))}
```

In this case, I want to look for this data while in another sheet. When I input the function below, it returns 0 every time. I am not sure which part of the formula is failing.

```
=MAX(IF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(($F$9&$F$10&$F$12),":",$F$10,$F$11))>=$E$4,ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(($F$9&$F$10&$F$12),":",$F$10,$F$11))),0))
```

Legend:

```
F9 (the sheet name): 'Data BBG'! 
F10 (column letter): I
F12 (starting row): 1298 
F11 (ending row): 1223 
E4 (threshold number): 25
```

The true answer given the numbers is 1295 (as confirmed directly in the Data sheet when I do not have to use indirect), but this is not the return using this formula.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why is the **starting row** below the **ending row** ??

Comment: Because my data is going in descending order.

Comment: I don't think it works if I switch the data order around (and make starting row above the ending row).

Comment: Have you tried breaking the formula into its parts?  Do just the concatenate fist and make sure it returns the string it should.  Also make sure you are using Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Yes I have done these things. The concatenation properly returns the below (slightly altered name of column and starting/ending row order. 'Data_BBG'!I634:I709 =CONCATENATE(($F$9&$F$10&$F$11),":",$F$10,$F$12)

Comment: Does F9 trully show the first `'` as that is a shortcut to tell excel that it is text.  Maybe try not put that in the cell but adding it in the formula: `CONCATENATE(("'" & $F$9&"'!"&$F$10&$F$12),":",$F$10,$F$11)`